# XML search algorithm C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to find out how to write XML search algorithm.

Following is the my File

```
    <DUMMYROOT>
<root>Job Started</root>
<root>Job Running</root>
</DUMMYROOT>
```

and I want search string as `<root>Job Started</root>`
I should be able to supply inner level of nodes as a search string like

```
<DUMMYROOT><root1><root2><root3>STRINGTOSEARCH</root3></root2></root1></DUMMYROOT>
```

and my file may not the complete XML when I am applying my Search Algorithm.

Comment: C++ does not have any support for XML built-in. You will have to use libraries like Expat. And those libraries will normally require that what you submit to them is well-formed XML - in other words "complete".

Comment: Yes I agree, unfortunately I may or may not have complete XML file when I execute my search routine

Comment: Your question is a bit fuzzy but if you want to do searching in XMLs you should take a look at XML querying languages like XPath or XQuery (my personal opinion being that XPath is the simplest of the two).

Comment: But XPath or XQuery will need wel-formed XML and another reason in I do not want to read the XML file from stat every time, My input xml file is getting update at regular interval, once I scan the file, next time i would like to scan it from last read offset.

Comment: This sounds like a misuse of XML to me. You would be much better served with some line or simple record based format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I wrote a few years ago that seems to fit reasonably well with what you're looking for (though make no mistake, it is kind of ugly, and if the XML is *really* badly formed, it might run into a problem).

```
template <class OutIt>
void split(string const &input, string const &sep, OutIt output) {
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t pos;
    do { 
        pos = input.find(sep, start);
        std::string temp(input, start, pos-start);
        *output++ = temp;
        start = pos+1;
    } while (pos != string::npos);
}

string extract(string const &input, string const &field, bool whole=false) { 
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    split(field, "\\", std::back_inserter(names));

    size_t b = 0, e = string::npos;
    std::string ret(input);

    for (size_t i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
        ret = std::string(ret, b, e-b);
        string sname  = "<" + names[i];
        string ename = "</" + names[i];
        if (whole) {
            sname+=">";
            ename+=">";
        }
        b = ret.find(sname);
        if (b==string::npos)
            return "";
        b = ret.find(">", b)+1;
        e = ret.find(ename, b);
        if (b==string::npos || e == string::npos)
            return "";
    }
    ret = std::string(ret, b, e-b);

    int pos;

    // minor cleanup: remove tabs from string before returning.        
    while ((pos=ret.find("\t"))!=std::string::npos)
        ret[pos] = ' ';

    return ret;
}
```

Normal use would be something like:

```
result = extract(input, "a\\b\\c\\d");
```

The "whole" parameter governs whether you've specified the "whole" tag, or whether it's allowed to have attributes in addition to what you've specified (e.g., `<tag>` vs. `<tag attribute = "value">`).

Comment: In what sense is `"a\\b\\c\\d"` XML?

Comment: It's not. It's a specifier for a "path" in the XML -- this example would look for something like `<a><b><c><d>text</d></c></b><a>` and return `text` (with, of course, the possibility that each of the outer tags might contain other "stuff" that it would ignore). Using the example in the original question, you'd search for `DUMMYROOT\\root1\\root2\\root3`, and it would return "STRINGTOSEARCH".

Comment: Oh, OK. Just as a matter of interest, what was the reason you chose backslash as the path separator?

Comment: @Neil: It was being used mostly by people who are accustomed to Windows, so I made an XML "Path" look as much like a DOS/Windows path as I could. It would be trivial to change it to something else (change the second parameter to `split` at the beginning of `extract`).

Comment: I am still confused with, what is input here.

Comment: `input` is a string containing the XML you want to search in.

Comment: extract("<root>Job Started</root>","Job Started\\root",false); is this correct.

Comment: sorry my mistake following seems to working for me,
extract("<root>Job Started</root>","root",true);

Answer (score 0):

If your file is incomplete then most xml parsers will choke when trying to read it. You might be better off just doing a string search against the file content.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but node based search will be a problem to me. like If I want to search <ROOT TAG><ELEMENT1><ELEMENT2>SEARCH STRING</ELEMENT2></ELEMENT1></ROOT TAG>